# Deploying Saiku UI on Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, saiku

When I try to deploy saiku-ui-2.4.war to Glassfish I get

> "There is no installed container capable of handling this application
> ROOT. Please see server.log for more details."

The server.log shows:

> [#|2013-08-16T17:50:36.595-0400|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|There
> is no installed container capable of handling this application ROOT|#]
>
> [#|2013-08-16T17:50:36.610-0400|INFO|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: There is no installed container capable of handling this application ROOT. Please see server.log for more details.|#]

Any idea how to get around this?  I searched Saiku's own forum with no luck.  I even have a post on there.

Saiku has a prepared package that comes with Tomcat.  Saiku UI is deployed as Tomcat ROOT application.  This package works fine but I want to try to deploy it on Glassfish.

What's interesting is Saiku has a download saiku-ui-master.  This is a separate UI package that needs node.js installed. I've gotten this to work but I want to run it on Glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!  Added WEB-INF and web.xml then it deployed with no issue!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to unpack content of the saiku-ui.war in docroot of your domain as there is static content only.